# Function Memo should give different results for different arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am creating a function memo return a function that, when called, will check if it has already computed the result for the given argument and return that value instead if possible.

Right now my key only contains the first argument passed in as my key to check if the function was already run.

```
const memo = function(func) {
    const memoizedFunc = function () {
    let result;
    if (memoizedFunc.cache[arguments[0]] !== undefined) {
      result = memoizedFunc.cache[arguments[0]];
    } else {
      result = func.apply(null, arguments);
      memoizedFunc.cache[arguments[0]] = result;
    }
    return result;
  }
   memoizedFunc.cache = {};
   return memoizedFunc;
  };
```

So if we run this using the test function:

```
function memoAdd(num1, num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

 memo(memoAdd(1, 2)));
 memo(memoAdd(1, 3))); // -> since it's the first argument that we use as 
 // the key, it will still pull up 3 as the answer even if the answer should
 // be four
```

Any idea how should I fix this so I'll give different results for different arguments?

Answer (score 0):

Your test call will fail because it is not passing a callable to memo, but the results of the function.

If the idea is to avoid repeated computation and merely return the same result, you could do it like this:

```
var function_cache = {};
const memo1 = function(f, args) {
  var sig = JSON.stringify(args);
  if (f.cache == undefined) {
     f.cache = {};
  }
  if (f.cache[sig] !== undefined) {
      console.log('Value from Cache');
      return f.cache[sig];
    }
      console.log('Value from Computation');
  f.cache[sig] = f.apply(null, args);
  return f.cache[sig];
}

function memoAdd(num1, num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

 console.log(memo1(memoAdd, [1, 2]));
 console.log(memo1(memoAdd, [1, 3]));
 console.log(memo1(memoAdd, [1, 2]));
 console.log(memo1(memoAdd, [1, 3]));
```

In this case, the hash `cache` is added to the function that is passed, and the arguments are converted to a string signature via JSON.stringify - which is used to look up the prior value and return it.

If your goal is to have a callable that does this so you don't need to wrap it in memo each time, you could tweak this:

```
const memo2 = function(f) {
  if (f.cache == undefined) {
     f.cache = {};
  }

  const newFunc = function() {
     var sig = JSON.stringify(arguments);
     if (f.cache[sig] !== undefined) {
        console.log('Value from Cache');
        return f.cache[sig];
      }
      console.log('Value from Computation');
      f.cache[sig] = f.apply(null, arguments);
      return f.cache[sig];
  }
  return newFunc;
}

function memoAdd(num1, num2){
    return num1 + num2;
}

var myFunc = memo2(memoAdd);
console.log(myFunc(1,2));
console.log(myFunc(1,3));
console.log(myFunc(1,2));
console.log(myFunc(1,3));
```

In this case the passed in function is locked-in by the closure, and we still cache results in f.cache.